# What caused the damage to Nirauan described in the "Hand of Thrawn" duology by Zahn?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

In *Specter of the Past*, when Luke Skywalker and Mara arrive on [Nirauan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nirauan/Legends), they see severe damage inflicted by what [Wookieepedia calls](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nirauan/Legends#History) a "superlaser" to the landscape and the ancient fortress that Thrawn's forces use.

Is it known from some canon which race/civilization inflicted the damage and under what circumstances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hand is thought to be made Of Hijarna stone which absorbs turbo laser like "water on a dry sponge". An Imp Star Destroyer would run out of power before doing the kind of damage they saw. Nothing I have read has discussed how the damage was done. though they mention in the book that whatever did it likely caused the valley to form, implying it was one giant shot that did the damage. My initial assumption was Zahn was going to come back and tell the story in another book since he is clearly fond of Thrawn. But who knows. Seems too powerful for anything in the unknown regions but the Hijarna fortress was built 1000 years before so for now I guess it's just a mystery

Answer (score 1):

Given than a single *Imperator*-class Star Destroyer has the firepower to completely liquify the surface of a planet, I imagine just about any good-sized warship could have caused damage as described in the book.